# Get datetime with phpExcel

Tags: php, datetime, phpexcel

My column has the format of cell: dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm, when reading these worksheets, I need to get this value only the date and save in mysql.

By default, I'm reading the date, and giving exploits to save it, but the date comes in a weird format.

Column date in cell: `13/11/2017 00:01`

My code:

```
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    //Get worksheet and built array with first row as header
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    //excel with first row header, use header as key
    if($header){
        $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
        $headingsArray = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',null, true, true, true);
        $headingsArray = $headingsArray[1];
        $r = -1;
        $namedDataArray = array();
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
            $dataRow = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,null, true, true, true);
            if ((isset($dataRow[$row]['A'])) && ($dataRow[$row]['A'] > '')) {
                ++$r;
                foreach($headingsArray as $columnKey => $columnHeading) {
                    $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading] = $dataRow[$row][$columnKey];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //excel sheet with no header
        $namedDataArray = $objWorksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);
    }
```

When reading the value directly is to give an echo: `43052.000717593`

My code to just get the date in the format I need and save

```
    $data_mailing_file = explode(" ", $value['field_date']);

    $dataP = explode('/', $data_mailing_file[0]);
    $data_save = $dataP[2].'-'.$dataP[1].'-'.$dataP[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `43052.000717593` is an MS Excel serialized timestamp value, a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if the spreadsheet is using the Mac calendar).

MS Excel formats that value using the format mask, which you say is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` and display that value as `13/11/2017 00:01`, which is exactly what I'd expect from that format mask.

If you want to format the date differently; then you could change the format mask before calling `rangeToArray()`. An Excel format mask of `yyyy-mm-dd` will give you the date only in an appropriate format.

Alternatively get that serialized timestamp value, and then use the `ExcelToPHP()` or `ExcelToPHPObject()` methods of `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` to give a unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object respectively, that you can then format however you want using PHP's `date()` function or the DateTime object's `format()` method.